# Why does std::map work, but std::unordered_map throw an error when used in a struct

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, clang

The top struct declaration works, but the bottom fails, why?

```cpp
class Trie {
public:
    struct Node {
        map<char, Node> map;
    };
};

class Trie {
public:
    struct Node {
        unordered_map<char, Node> map;
    };
};
```

- Compiler: clang 11
- C++ Version: 17

Error:

```
In file included from prog_joined.cpp:1:
In file included from ./precompiled/headers.h:13:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/cmath:1927:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/specfun.h:45:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:215:11: error: field has incomplete type 'Trie::Node'
      _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>' requested here
    : std::aligned_storage<sizeof(_Tp), __alignof__(_Tp)>
                           ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:233:43: note: in instantiation of template class '__gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>>' requested here
      __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<_Value> _M_storage;
                                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:279:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>>' requested here
    struct _Hash_node<_Value, false> : _Hash_node_value_base<_Value>
                                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2028:25: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>, false>' requested here
        rebind_traits<typename __node_type::value_type>;
                               ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:184:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>, false>>>' requested here
      private __detail::_Hashtable_alloc<
              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:105:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::_Hashtable<char, std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<char>, std::hash<char>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>>' requested here
      _Hashtable _M_h;
                 ^
Line 25: Char 35: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::unordered_map<char, Trie::Node, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, Trie::Node>>>' requested here
        unordered_map<char, Node> map;
                                  ^
Line 24: Char 12: note: definition of 'Trie::Node' is not complete until the closing '}'
    struct Node {
           ^
```

Stack Overflow is giving me this "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error so here is some random text.

Comment: Looks to me like instantiating unordered_map requires instantiating std::pair<Key,Value> and std pair needs the full declaration of Node to be instantiated but because youre in the middle of that you get an error. Typically 'recursive' structures like this only work if all you need is something that doesnt depend on the full declaration of the struct (like a pointer) but if you need say the alignment or the size of the struct or any other detail it wont work.

Comment: One is trying to hash it which would require the full definition, clearly the other isn’t doing that if it works.

Comment: I don't think either of these is guaranteed to work. Neither [map](http://eel.is/c++draft/map.overview), nor [unordered_map](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.map.overview) has permission for incomplete types to be used, unlike, for example [vector](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview#4), which does.

Comment: Why would either be trying to hash it? In both versions `Node` is the _value_ type, not the key type.

Comment: Thanks the incomplete types for template instantiation appears to be precisely the issue I was having; I'd never heard of this concept before. I solved my issue by using unordered_map<char, Node*> instead of just <char, Node>